# Is it bad for yolov4 if the object is small?

Tags: annotations, training-data, conv-neural-network, yolo

I'm trying to use yolov4 for detect license plate and inside the license plate I should detect the numbers/letters (different class for each digit).
I'd like to train 2 yolov4 model - one for the license plate one for the digits.
I have annotation for both the license plate and digits.
Is it better if I train one model for the license plate (with the original image) and a different model for the digits (with the cropped image - only the license plate) or
Is it enough to use the original image both of the models?

So my question would be - can yolo detect (precisely) small object (digits) on a photo or is it better if the object is bigger (in proportion of the image)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can start training both images types at once and test.

For your second question, you will need to test it, as yolo can varies performance for a lot of other reasons than the proportion of your annotated objects.